# How to order an object in JavaScript with unknown property

Tags: javascript

I need to create dynamic objects ordering by the value, but I don't know the name of the property, I tried to use `_.sortby` but that did not work because I don't know the property

Initial object:

```
{
    134:0,
    135:1,
    136:2,
    137:3,
    138:4,
    139:5,
    140:15,
    141:16,
    142:17,
    143:18,
    144:19,
    145:6,
    146:7,
    147:11,
    148:12,
    149:13,
    150:14,
    470:10,
    471:20,
    768:8,
    769:9,
    770:21,
    771:22,
    772:23,
    773:24,
    774:25
}
```

The final object must be like this:

```
{
    134:0,
    135:1,
    136:2,
    137:3,
    138:4,
    139:5,
    145:6,
    146:7,
    768:8,
    769:9,
    470:10,
    147:11,
    148:12,
    149:13,
    150:14,
    140:15,
    141:16,
    142:17,
    143:18,
    144:19,
    471:20,
    770:21,
    771:22,
    772:23,
    773:24,
    774:25
}
```

Comment: Objects in JavaScript don't have an order except the order in which they were added to the object. If the keys are actually numbers, use an Array or Set.

Comment: If you can manipulate your response, just add key and sorting to it.

Comment: What is the purpose of sorting an object properties? To find their maximum value?

Comment: I need to order it to make a mold for order elements

Answer (score 0):

You may want to sort the Object keys, then map them to their values:

```
var obj={134:0 135:1 136:2 137:3 138:4 139:5 140:15 141:16 142:17};
```

Get the values sorted after keys:

```
console.log(Object.keys(obj).sort().map(key=>obj[key]));//[0,1,2,3,4,5,15,16,17]
```

Note that you cannot *sort* objects keys. That why the upper code returns an array.

Comment: but I need the name of the property to , the vales are only for order it

Comment: @JavierGutierrez you can not !

Answer (score 0):

Create an array whose indexes are the object property values, and values are the property names. Then the order of this array will be the order of the properties that you want in your result.

```js
var object = {
    134:0,
    135:1,
    136:2,
    137:3,
    138:4,
    139:5,
    140:15,
    141:16,
    142:17,
    143:18,
    144:19,
    145:6,
    146:7,
    147:11,
    148:12,
    149:13,
    150:14,
    470:10,
    471:20,
    768:8,
    769:9,
    770:21,
    771:22,
    772:23,
    773:24,
    774:25
};

var array = [];
for (var key in object) {
    array[object[key]] = key;
}
var newObject = {};
array.forEach(function(el, i) {
    newObject[el] = i;
});

console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can change the order of an object properties in JavaScript.
 But you could take a pick by sorting its values and storing them in array with the property key and value:

```js
var o = { 134:0, 135:1, 136:2, 137:3, 138:4, 139:5, 140:15, 141:16, 142:17, 143:18, 144:19, 145:6, 146:7, 147:11, 148:12, 149:13, 150:14, 470:10, 471:20, 768:8, 769:9, 770:21, 771:22, 772:23, 773:24, 774:25};

console.log(Object.keys(o).sort((a, b)=>{ return o[a]-o[b];}).map((e)=>{ return {key: e, value: o[e]};}));
```

Comment: the problem is like this I have an array of objects and I wanna order it cause each property is a colum, for order first y make an object who contains the necesary order this is the initial object

initial{

3:46,
8:25,
5:45,
10:78,
area:'area'
state:'state'


}
the first value are the id

but  the real order must be like this
        
 mold{
  10:78,
  3:46,
  5:45,
  8:25
     }

after i know the real order I need to order the initial objet to 
initial=mold;

initial{

10:78,
3:46,
5:45,
8:25,
area:'area'
state:'state'


}